# XSLT Strip All Tabs In Text Output

Tags: xslt, formatting

Silly, simple question.  When I output text, it still get the tabs based on my formatted/indented XSL structure.  How do I instruct the transformer to ignore the spacing in the stylesheet while still keeping it neatly formatted?

```
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="text"/>

      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Foo/Bar"></xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="Bar">   
<xsl:for-each select="AAA"><xsl:for-each select="BBB"><xsl:value-of select="Label"/>|<xsl:value-of select="Value"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text></xsl:for-each></xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

      </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces output line by line with no tabs:

```
SomeLabel|SomeValue
SomeLabel|SomeValue
SomeLabel|SomeValue


      <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Foo/Bar"></xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Bar">   
    <xsl:for-each select="AAA">   
        <xsl:for-each select="BBB">   
            <xsl:value-of select="Label"/>|<xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
             <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces output with tabs:

```
SomeLabel|SomeValue
    SomeLabel|SomeValue
    SomeLabel|SomeValue
```

**Update:**
Adding this does not fix it:

```
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"></xsl:strip-space>
```

This is contrived, but you can imagine the XML looks like this:

```
<Foo>
  <Bar>
    <AAA>
      <BBB>
        <Label>SomeLabel1</Label>
        <Value>SomeValue1</Value>
      </BBB>
      <BBB>    
        <Label>SomeLabel2</Label>
        <Value>SomeValue2</Value>
      </BBB>
      <BBB>
        <Label>SomeLabel3</Label>
        <Value>SomeValue3</Value>
      </BBB>
    </AAA>
  </Bar>
</Foo>
```

Comment: The XSLT code you have posted does not produce the results you claim: http://xsltransform.net/pPgCcop

Comment: @michael.hor257k Updated.  The indenting is correct on xsltransform.net, but I ran this in visual studio and notepad++ and both inserted tabs into the output when the XSLT was tab indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could try is wrapping all your current text nodes in **xsl:text**. For example, try this

```
  <xsl:for-each select="BBB">
    <xsl:value-of select="Label"/>
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively, you could make use of the **concat** function.

```
  <xsl:for-each select="BBB">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(Label, '|')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(Value, '|')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

You could even combine the two statements into one if you wanted

```
  <xsl:for-each select="BBB">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(Label, '|', Value, '|')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

EDIT: If you prefer not to enter the separator `|` so many times, you make use of template matching to output the fileds. First, replace the **value-of** with **apply-templates** like so

```
    <xsl:for-each select="BBB">   
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Label"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Value"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Then you would have one specific template to match **Label**, where you wouldn't need to output the separator, and another more generic template matching any child of **BBB**

```
<xsl:template match="BBB/Label" priority="1">
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="BBB/*">
   <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

(The **priority** here is needed to ensure **Label** is matched by the first template, and not the general one). Of course, you could also not do **apply-templates** on **Label** in this case, and just do **xsl:value-of** for that one.

Furthermore, if the fields were being output in the order they appear in the XML, you could simplify the **for-each** to just this

```
    <xsl:for-each select="BBB">   
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: This works, and I consider this a partial solution.  Works great if I have two fields, but in reality I would have to concatenate about 50 fields.  Is there not a method to address this universally without applying concat to everything you need?

Comment: Also, this still includes a tab before every Label.

Comment: @kakridge "*in reality I would have to concatenate about 50 fields.*" We can only go by what you show us. In your code, you call each "field" explicitly, so adding a text element to each such call is no great effort. Alternatively, you could construct a for-each "field" loop and insert the text element into it, once.

Comment: Sure, it's not a great effort, but I'm lazy and would prefer an approach that ignores all whitespace outside of elements in the entire stylesheet.  What I'm hearing is that is not possible.

Comment: Thanks guys, the xsl:text element is an acceptable answer.  Still disappointed there is no way to ignore all whitespace in the stylesheet with a processing directive.  Perhaps strip-space is supposed to do that, but it is not working with the processing tools I am using.

Comment: @kakridge I've made an edit to my answer which shows an alternate approach which could be of use. You can read up about white-space stripping at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip. Note that strip-space only applies to the source document. Also bear in mind that 'stripping' is not the same as 'trimming'. As stated in the W3C document "Stripping the text node removes the text node from the tree" and "A text node is never stripped unless it contains only whitespace characters"

Comment: All good stuff, but still cumbersome.  I do appreciate you thinking about it differently though.  What I really need is the ability to strip away tabs/equivalent spaces in the stylesheet.  Not a huge deal, I guess the easiest thing to do is linearize the stylesheet prior to processing.